# Protocol for deleting wrong answers.

Tags: discussion, deletion

Assume someone asks a question, I read it and think "ok I've got it". And post my answer. After some amount of time I realize, or am alerted that my answer is wrong. Perhaps it was too sloppy, or missed a special case, or even maybe I misunderstood the question. Also assume that in the mean time, someone else has answered the question correctly. Their answer has been accepted and all is well.

Should I delete my answer?

I don't think this matter is super important, I was just curious.

Answer (score 18):

If it's entirely wrong and of no value to future visitors, why not delete it? It's less clutter that way.

If your answer *does* have something of value not covered by other answers, please don't delete it just because something else is better, although you can edit it to remove the incorrect or irrelevant parts.

Comment: I agree with this, I was mostly curious to see if there is another perspective I am overlooking.

Comment: If you post something wrong and somebody enlightens you in the comment, edit your question accordingly and leave the enlightening comment for the rest of the world :)

Comment: I would only add: Put a comment on your answer before you delete it.  "I just realized this is wrong because ____; deleting now."