# Why was my post deleted

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

My post for the question - On taking on taking square roots, by Niki -was interesting to me ,I posted 2 answers pertaining to comments and relevant to the question.For some reason the posts were deleted by a geru. I am not complaining that the post should receive points but I strongly object to its removal I only post to be helpful to the community. My remarks address an important issue in foundations that is much misunderstood.

Comment: Undoubtedly you are referring to this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2603184/11619). Posting the link here so that users who want to comment can do so with minimum effort (Stuart, 10k+ users can see deleted posts, so they can comment on the content of your answer)

Comment: Reason number (1)  Each of your two deleted answers were addressed to other answerers, about their posts.  If you want to comment to an answerer, then *comment*, in a *comment* below their post(s).  Comments don't belong in answer fields.  Now, if you're willing to write up your own solution as an answer, do so.

Comment: What or who is a "geru"?  The two non-answers were deleted by "a geru", you claim?

Comment: @amWhy: "It's pitch black, you're likely to be eaten by a [grue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grue_(monster))". I guess in the context of MSE, "It's very low quality, your post is likely to be deleted by a grue" instead.

Comment: But then, @AsafKaragila, we must consider that the context in which the posts are said to have been deleted by an $\color{orange}{\text{urge}}$?

Answer (score 5):

I imagine that your post was deleted for several reasons:

1) As amWhy has explained in their comment, you posted answers that were really commentary on another answer, rather than an attempt to answer the original question. Since you have more than 50 reputation, you have the privilege to post comments on people's answers, which is what you should do in this situation in the future.

2) Your answers were unformatted, poorly-written, and poorly-organized. No, one shouldn't conflate content with style, but on a site all about mathematics communication, I urge you to exercise a basic level of care when crafting your posts in the future. This includes double-checking that your write in complete, grammatically-correct sentences and formatting your math using LaTeX.

3) Your answers were mathematically suspect (conflating set-valued and multi-valued functions, and calling $\sqrt{4}$ a "variable," for instance). On this site, we don't delete answers just for being wrong, but the technical inaccuracies and imprecisions in your posts likely aggravated, rather than mitigated, the above two issues in the minds of the users who voted to delete your answers.

Comment: If unattended, [deleting answers for being wrong](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27424) is likely not a bad choice.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to user7530's answer to emphasize the importance of point (2).

I briefly reviewed your previous answers. Based on a random sample of roughly 10 of your answers, it appears that you have never written a properly formatted or grammatical answer. Now since many of your posts have a positive score despite this, I imagine the mathematical content must be good. Unfortunately, I and future users don't have the time to try to decipher your (basically) illegible posts.

To be perfectly blunt, your answers are the sort of answers I would typically downvote if I came across them on the main page, or vote to delete if I saw them in the LQ review queue. (Obviously I didn't do that in this case, as I was reviewing many of your questions to try to figure out what happened.) *On reviewing my answer before posting I feel that this is a little extreme. I'd probably edit the posts, if your posts were a new user's posts, however I'll address this later.*

Why do I say your answers are low quality? Nothing is divorced from its presentation. An answer is only as helpful as it is clear, and with the blatant disregard for punctuation, paragraphs, or formatting in your answers, I have to say that none of your answers (as originally written by you) qualify as clear. Thus even if the content is good, the community doesn't have the time to be cleaning up your illegible answers.

I say this having edited many similar questions and answers when I've seen them before. However, those were typically from new users. At 100 answers and over 1000 rep, you don't qualify as a new user, and I have no patience for your apparent disregard for the community.

[Lol, apparently I've even edited one of your (recent) answers before.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2595202/90543)

Anyway, to summarize, I regard your answer quality as basically unacceptable, and view deletion as a reasonable consequence given that you've made no effort to attempt to improve your posts in your time here.

That said, the mathematical content of your posts seems to typically be good. However, as a person who typically edits low quality posts to improve them, I feel your blatant disregard for even the most basic standards of punctuation or formatting in your posts as an experience user is basically just rude and insulting.

You will receive a more positive response from me and others if you would start formatting your posts properly, and you could begin by at least using MathJax. To get started, you can read [the tutorial here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/90543)

Comment: i try my best to use MathJax but the tutorial is so unwieldy and hard to use without errors ;and there is no place for me to practice or keep notes that I tend to miss things . Sorry

Comment: @StuartMN Both the Web site and the app have a "preview" option for answers, where you can see - as you type - what your answer would look like when it finally appears. Note, nobody is forcing you to actually *post* an answer - you can use this facility as a pure playground. You can also choose the "Edit" option on posts and answers to see their source in MathJax - again nobody is making you do an actual edit, and once you've seen how they have, for example, formatted a particular expression, you can cancel the edit. HTH

Comment: @StuartMN You said that there was no place to practice. What about [Sandbox for drafts of long, complex posts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4666)?